# No entiendo por qué me arroja el error "Invalid numeric literal" en este código PHP

Tags: php

Me pasa algo muy extraño en este código.

Resulta que estoy escribiendo un bloque `switch`  de esta manera:

```
switch ($intIdElemento)
{
    case 01: 
        // ... código
        break;

    case 02: 
        // ... código
        break;

    case 03: 
        // ... código
        break;

    case 04: 
        // ... código
        break;

    case 05: 
        // ... código
        break;

    case 06: 
        // ... código
        break;

    case 07: 
        // ... código
        break;

    case 08:           //¡ERROR!
        // ... código
        break;

    default:
        break;

}
```

Me permite evaluar case numéricos escritos con el cero delante sólo hasta el `07`. Cuando pongo desde `case 08:` en adelante, el color del número cambia en el editor y si ejecuto el código no funciona, me arroja este error:

> PHP Parse error:  Invalid numeric literal in ...

La línea indicada es la de cualquier case escrito con un cero delante y cuyo valor sea mayor que siete.

**¿A qué se debe que no admita valores así a partir de `08`?**

Estoy usando la versión **`7.0.12`** de PHP.

Comment: Me imagino que tendrá algo que ver con interpretar los números en octal en lugar de en decimal, pero no sabría decir por qué. No puedo reproducir el problema en PHP 5.6. ¿Qué versión de PHP estás usando?

Comment: Estoy usando la versión `7.0.12` de PHP @AlvaroMontoro, acabo de agregarlo a la pregunta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[El error se debe a un cambio que hubo en php 7.x para que 08 no sea tratado como un octal literal](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70193). Segun el cometario de nikic@php.net(el ultimo en la pagina):

> Los números que empiezan por 0 son literales octales. 08 no es un
>   literal octal válido, por lo que obtendrá un error ahora.
>   Anteriormente se trataba en silencio como 0.

La comendacion que dan es especificarlos como string y funciona perfecto:

```
$intIdElemento = '08';
switch ($intIdElemento)
{
    case 01: 
        // ... código
        break;

    case 02: 
        // ... código
        break;

    case 03: 
        // ... código
        break;

    case 04: 
        // ... código
        break;

    case 05: 
        // ... código
        break;

    case 06: 
        // ... código
        break;

    case 07: 
        // ... código
        break;
     case '08': //¡PERFECTO!

        break;

    default:
        break;

}
```

Comment: ¡Excelente! Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 5):

Simple:

> Para utilizar la notación octal, se antepone al número un 0 (cero).

PHP reconoce varias *bases numéricas*:

- Decimal (base 10): números *corrientes y molientes*, **que no empiecen por `0`**.
- Hexadecimal (base 16): se antepone `0x` al número: `0xF` => 15.
- Octal (base 8): se comienza el número por un `0`.

El último punto es el responsable de tu problema: los dígitos en base octal **no pueden ser mayores a `7`**.

Es el mismo error que se produciría sin intentaras `0x14G8` -> **Tampoco** es un número válido **en base hexadecimal**.

Más información:

[Wikipedia: Sistema octal.](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_numeraci%C3%B3n_octal)

[Wikipedia: Sistema hexadecimal.](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_hexadecimal)

[php.net: Números enteros.](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.integer.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tan detallada explicación.

Answer (score -1):

A mi me daba el mismo error usando Laravel, lo solucione colocando el valor de Case entre comillas, para que lo tome literal y no numerico.

```
@switch($mes)
                @case("01")
                    Enero
                    @break
                @case("02")
                    Febrero
                    @break
                @case("03")
                    Marzo
                    @break
                @case("04")
                    Abril
                    @break
                @case("05")
                    Mayo
                    @break
                @case("06")
                    Junio
                    @break
                @case("07")
                    Julio
                    @break
                @case("08")
                    Agosto
                    @break
                @case("09")
                    Septiembre
                    @break
                @case("10")
                    Octubre
                    @break
                @case("11")
                    Noviembre
                    @break
                @case("12")
                    Diiembre
                    @break
            @endswitch
```